# Find duplicate values in array of hash values using perl

Tags: perl

I want to find duplicate values for hash values which is an array. I can able to get the duplicate values for individual keys. But I want to get the duplicate values of arrays for all the keys
For example, in the below source, I need to get the output as

```
2 has the duplicate value d
3 has the duplicate value a
1 and 3 has duplicate value a
```

**Source code tried:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @test1 = qw(a b c);
my @test2 = qw(d e d);
my @test3 = qw(a h a);
my %hash = ( "1" => \@test1,
             "2" => \@test2,
             "3" => \@test3,
            );
while( my ($key, $values) = each %hash ) {
  my %seen = ();
  my @dup = map { 1==$seen{$_}++ ? $_ : () } @$values;
  if( $#dup > -1 ) {
    my $dupkey = join (" ",@dup);
    print "$key has the duplicate value $dupkey\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it can be done more elegantly, but my Perl is a bit rusty now :) Nice exercise by the way :)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @test1 = qw(a b c);
my @test2 = qw(d e d);
my @test3 = qw(a h a e);
my @test4 = qw(b d f e);
my %hash = ( "1" => \@test1,
             "2" => \@test2,
             "3" => \@test3,
             "4" => \@test4
            );
my %seen;
while( my ($key, $values) = each %hash ) {
  foreach (@{$values}) { 
    if (exists $seen{$_}) {
      if (exists $seen{$_}{$key}) {
        $seen{$_}{$key}+=1;
      } else {
        $seen{$_}{$key}=1;
      }
    } else {
      $seen{$_}{$key} = 1;
    }
  }
  my @dup = grep { exists $seen{$_}{$key} && $seen{$_}{$key}>1 } keys %seen;
  if( $#dup > -1 ) {
    my $dupkey = join (" ",@dup);
    print "$key has the duplicate value $dupkey\n";
  }
}
my @dupall = sort grep { scalar(keys $seen{$_})>1 } keys %seen;
foreach( @dupall ) {
    my @ardupkeys = sort keys $seen{$_};
    my $dupkeys = join(" and ",(join(",", @ardupkeys[0..$#ardupkeys-1]),$ardupkeys[-1]));
    print "$dupkeys have the duplicate value $_\n";
  }
```

output:

```
3 has the duplicate value a
2 has the duplicate value d
1 and 3 have the duplicate value a
1 and 4 have the duplicate value b
2 and 4 have the duplicate value d
2,3 and 4 have the duplicate value e
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict; use warnings;

my @test1 = qw(a b c);
my @test2 = qw(d e d);
my @test3 = qw(a h a);
my %hash = ( "1" => \@test1,
             "2" => \@test2,
             "3" => \@test3,
            );

my %seen_in;

# sorted values look better
for my $key ( sort keys %hash ) {
  my $values = $hash{$key};
  my %count = ();

  my @dup = map { push(@{$seen_in{$_}},$key) unless $count{$_};  1==$count{$_}++ ? ($_) : () } @$values;
  for my $dupkey (@dup) {
    print "$key has the duplicate value $dupkey\n";
  }
}

for my $dupval (map {@{$seen_in{$_}}>1 ? ($_):()} sort keys %seen_in) {
   print join(" and ", @{$seen_in{$dupval}}), " have the duplicate value $dupval\n";
}
```

Comment: sorting adds extra complexity :}

Comment: @Ashalynd **BUT** it simplifies reading/analyzing the results by brainware :-)

Comment: yeah, that's also true :}

Comment: @Andrzej A. Filip Your code working fine now, Thanks

Comment: `sort keys %hash` should be a numeric sort

Comment: @Borodin You MAY be right but I bet the opposite. We may only guess relation between sample (simplified) data and real data.

Answer (score 0):

With a little help from CPAN and friends, you can write a solution that scales well.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(combinations);
use Array::Utils qw(intersect);


my @test1 = qw(a b c);
my @test2 = qw(d e d);
my @test3 = qw(a h a);
my %hash = ( "1" => \@test1,
             "2" => \@test2,
             "3" => \@test3,
);

my @keys = keys %hash;

for my $key (keys %hash) {
    my %seen;
    $seen{$_}++ for @{$hash{$key}};
    print "$key has the duplicate value $_\n" for map {$seen{$_} > 1 ? $_ : ()} keys %seen;
}

my $combination = combinations(\@keys, 2);
while (my $pair = $combination->next) {
    my %common  = map { $_ => 1 } intersect(@{$hash{@$pair[0]}}, @{$hash{@$pair[1]}});
    print "@$pair[0] and @$pair[1] has duplicate value $_\n" for keys %common;
}
```

**Output**:

```
3 has the duplicate value a
2 has the duplicate value d
1 and 3 has duplicate value a
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that builds a similar hash to Andrzej's version but avoids using `map`.

I have assumed that you want to know only whether a value appears more than once in *any* set. If you need precisely what you have shown in your question then see below.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @test1 = qw(a b c);
my @test2 = qw(d e d);
my @test3 = qw(a h a);

my %hash = (
  1 => \@test1,
  2 => \@test2,
  3 => \@test3,
);

my %appears;

while (my ($set, $contents) = each %hash) {
  ++$appears{$_}{$set} for @$contents;
}

for my $item (sort keys %appears) {
  my $sets = $appears{$item};
  my $count;
  $count += $_ for values %$sets;
  next unless $count > 1;

  my @sets = sort { $a <=> $b } keys %$sets;

  printf "%s %s the duplicate value %s\n",
      join(', ', @sets) =~ s/,([^,]+\z)/ and$1/r,
      @sets > 1 ? 'have' : 'has',
      $item;
}
```

**output**

```
1 and 3 have the duplicate value a
2 has the duplicate value d
```

If you really want duplicates *within* a set reported separately from duplicates *across* all sets then just the display code needs to change. Replace the final `for` loop with this

```
for my $item (sort keys %appears) {
  my $sets = $appears{$item};
  my @sets = grep { $sets->{$_} > 1 } sort { $a <=> $b } keys %$sets;
  print "@sets has the duplicate value $item\n" if @sets;
}

for my $item (sort keys %appears) {
  my $sets = $appears{$item};
  next unless keys %$sets > 1;

  my @sets = sort { $a <=> $b } keys %$sets;

  printf "%s have the duplicate value %s\n",
      join(', ', @sets) =~ s/,([^,]+\z)/ and$1/r,
      $item;
}
```

**output**

```
3 has the duplicate value a
2 has the duplicate value d
1 and 3 have the duplicate value a
```